# CSS - nth-child(even) of specific class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a table looking something like this

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="row">...</tr>
  <tr class="row--expanded">...</tr>
  <tr class="row">...</tr>
  <tr class="row--expandable">...</tr>
  <tr class="row">...</tr>
  <tr class="row">...</tr>
  <tr class="row--expanded">...</tr>
</tbody>
```

Table consists of rows that can be expanded( not every row, only the ones that are set to be expandable). I want to have an optional zebra style and before adding expansion options I used

```
tbody {
  tr:nth-child(even) {
  ...
  }
}
```

But now since I also have optional expansion rows it wont work. How can I apply nth-child(even) but only to elements with class .row?

````
tbody {
  .row:nth-child(even) {
  ...
  }
}
``` Does not work
````

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to also have the `row` class on all the rows, though you may need to update some css to allow that:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="row">...</tr>
  <tr class="row row--expanded">...</tr>
  <tr class="row">...</tr>
  <tr class="row row--expandable">...</tr>
  <tr class="row">...</tr>
  <tr class="row">...</tr>
  <tr class="row row--expanded">...</tr>
</tbody>
```